# Open-source/COTS Remote monitoring software?

Tags: remote

I'm looking for a piece of software (the freer the better!) that could be used to track the CPU/Memory changes on a remote system when I remotely startup a component, and have that software report back to the system I'm running from. The components being run remotely also communicate with components on my system, and if I could track the network status (message exchange rate, etc), that'd be great! Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, [Zenoss](http://www.zenoss.com/) does want you want, and is extensible to an extent, with Zenpacks, and is free for Zenoss Core, but I might be mis-understanding your question. (?)

Josh

Comment: Interesting. Sorry for not being specific enough. I'm basically looking for a product that does two things:

1. monitors the health (ie. latency, bandwidth, etc.) of a DDS network cloud.

2. monitors the CPU/memory usage of a system

Obviously, the second isn't a huge deal. But if I could find a product that could do both, it would be great!

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote I'm basically looking for a product that does two things: 1. monitors the health (ie. latency, bandwidth, etc.) of a DDS network cloud. 2. monitors the CPU/memory usage of a system Obviously, the second isn't a huge deal. 
>   Blockquote

Checkout Smokeping for #1: http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It's not open source, but is it COTS. 
Maybe you could try [IP Monitor](http://www.solarwinds.com/products/ipmonitor/)?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I'll definitely look into both of those. I'm quite new to this, so I'm not sure how prevalent DDS monitoring is. And really, I don't need anything highly fleshed out. I'll basically be taking the log/dump that is produced, and send it through the processes of the components I'm monitoring to analyze by a higher level program I've also built.